# Difference between Lync Basic and Lync Regular when upgraded to Skype for business

Tags: skype, lync, patch, lync-2013

I have 10 workstations that had Lync Basic, and 10 workstations that had the full Lync client.

Now that I deployed patches, they are both Skype For Business.

Is there any difference between the installations? In features or functionality?

Below is a picture of a Lync Basic and a Lync full client, each upgraded to Skype For Business.

Notice the different product IDs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If they are all running the same version of Skype for business and there are no disabled items then they should be the same.

The way to check is to check the about Skype for Business page
Click the cog, help, About Skype for Business

[image]

Then check the version and if anything is disabled.

[image]

Comment: I uploaded my version number as well.. also different from you in two areas of the product.   The disabled section is blank

Comment: How did you get to version 2015? Where did that come from?  I'm doing windows updates...